# Typescript: limiting types in object values

Tags: oop, typescript, typescript-typings, typing

I'm trying to create a large object whose values are limited to only 3 types: `Texture`, `Geometry`, `Script`

My object would look something like this:

```
var assets: Assets = {
    sky: <Texture>,
    ground: <Texture>,
    city: <Geometry>,
    people: <Script>,
    cars: <Script>,
    sun: <Circle> // <--This should fail because it's not one of the 3 types
    //...
}
```

How can I declare the `Assets` interface so the value in each key-value pair is limited to these 3 types? I tried starting with:

```
interface Assets{
    key: Texture | Geometry | Script;
}
```

but then it breaks when I assign

```
this.assets = {sky: new Texture()}
```

Because it's expecting only `key` instead of `sky`. Is there any way of achieving this without nesting objects within objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
type Assets = {
    [key: string]: Texture | Geometry | Script;
}
```

That type will allow for string keys and values of one of the types you requested.

More on the subject: [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)

Comment: That's it! I had tried <key:string> and `key: string: Texture...` and who knows what else. I'm still trying to understand the difference between <> and [] sometimes.

Comment: `<>` are for generics (and type assertion) only