# TypeScript declare object structure without using [key:string]

Tags: typescript

I'm working on an interface with the following structure:

```
interface IAsset {
    file: string,
    type: number
}
```

Now I want to create an object that allows any key, but the value is always of type `IAsset`:

```
const list = {
    bike: {
        file: "./meshes/bike.fbx",
        type: 0,
    },
    sky: {
        file: "./textures/sky.jpg",
        type: 1,
        style: "red" // <-- should yield error
    }
};
```

I've tried the approach outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45644452/typescript-limiting-types-in-object-values) by implementing a new type:

```
type AssetList{[key: string], IAsset}
```

but I don't want to access my elements with a string, for instance `list["bike"]`, because then I could request non-existing elements, like `list["apple"]` without an error (plus, I also lose the autocomplete functionality).

How can I tell TypeScript that each value in that object should be of type `IAsset` without string-based accessors?

Comment: The simple solution is `{ [key: string]: IAsset | undefined }`, so when you access `list['bike']` the type is `IAsset | undefined`, forcing you to handle the case where it didn't exist.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks, but that's exactly why I'm asking for an alternative to the `[key: string]` approach. Having to handle `undefined` cases invalidates the reason why I'm creating an object literal. I want to only have access to existing properties.

Comment: I see - in that case I misunderstood the requirement. Looks like you've now got a good answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing around, I found the [`Record`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) method a bit convoluted, and too abstract to fully grasp. Additionally, importing this variable into other files required a weird `Record<"bike"|"sky", IAsset>` interface that was cumbersome to declare and update each time I needed to add one more element.

Instead, I just created a class, and declared each property as its own `IAsset` type. Now I could easily import `AssetListClass` alongside `AssetList` into other files.

```
interface IAsset {
    file: string,
    type: number
}

export class AssetListClass {
    bike: IAsset = {
        file: "meshes/bike.fbx",
        type: 0
    };
    sky: IAsset = {
        file: "./textures/sky.jpg",
        type: 1,
    }
}

export const AssetList = new AssetListClass();
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no single type that represents what you're looking for: an object type with *known keys*, all of whose property values are of type `IAsset`.  However, you can express this as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type `AssetList<K>` depending on the set of keys `K`, like this:

```
type AssetList<K extends PropertyKey> = Record<K, IAsset>;
```

Then you can write `const list: AssertList<"bike"|"sky"> = {...}`, but presuming you want the compiler to infer the keys for you, you can use a helper function instead of a type annotation:

```
const asAssetList = <K extends PropertyKey>(a: AssetList<K>) => a;
```

And use it like this:

```
const list = asAssetList({
  bike: {
    file: "./meshes/bike.fbx",
    type: 0,
  },
  sky: {
    file: "./textures/sky.jpg",
    type: 1,
    // style: "red" // excess property warning here
  }
});
```

If don't comment out `style: "red"` you'll get an [excess property warning](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) as you expect.

And then `list` will remember exactly the keys it has:

```
list.bike.file; // okay
list.sky.type; // okay
list.oops.file; // error, oops does not exist
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEDOmJmQb2QFgAoZc5GYAGwgC5lMwpQBzAGlIuTAE8AHeshABXALYAjaKQC+pUn0HIsOMABlgTADwBpZBAAekEABNMyAApQA9oKh8dEXgD5kAXmQAlCAmtQTuuxoKrjOANykviBMyHCYIeqaeB66+kYQpuZWttAOTs4AFHAMCRraOs4AlO6ucBEkkdbReNRJ7rHx2LhlYAX4XMgSwADWQv1kFFS0DABEAHQA9GIQmAAWKwtDo3MwEgYznBPkikIADIfkMheMw7wM49xTQvMLkEYiUBuYt3MAVvysA4DY4CIQARmu5AWC0YfGmyBmnxMM2Q0LSSGwyH4NjsfGQAHc4FAQGxkOtPgM5CQZJV6qRWkw5lsIDsaBAwqiYdZhnBePSknNvrw5icOWjubz+YzrLZMKzaGKYdAbFAgjL+OYTNYVsJrHhDElSEA)

Comment: Works wonderfully! I didn't know about the `Record` keyword. For anyone interested, [here's its definition](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt)

Comment: I came up with a simpler alternative (below). Not quite the same as yours, but I get a more concise type to import into other files :)

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution would be to do a type assertion on the object:

```
const obj = {
    a : 1,
    b : 2,
}

type RecordType = {[key: string]: number}

// Make sure that the object conforms to {string: number}, but don't
//   modify the original type
{ const _ = obj as RecordType }

// ERROR: Property "c" does not exist on obj
console.log(obj.c)

const obj2 = {
    a : "somestring",
    b : 2
}

// ERROR: ob2 has a string as a value, instead of a number
{ const _ = obj2 as RecordType }
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMCGMAXDAIwA02u8RMATBQL6aZQCeADgKYwBKnoAJwAmAFQ7c06ANoBrTq2LQBASzABzALrEwAVwC28TgKaYA9KZgBZPHJgQdA7lAAWeWC+4JE-WKDAAzEAE9CBgoEAwlVTVtfUNjMhh4HVghcAByKDMLHD0QIWV-VjDnTxU1VTwAGzDxTHQYP2gYAH1UOCR8UL5BUXEYE3MYAFEeHgB5HmIABQEQLgE2GAAiYGWYNM5QsBBYTgAPZWbwDsRMJpAqzgA6KpA1AAova+AASmYm2C9adqxcfBoywgID0WygKnUywo-2oxFomEGFlGEymHR+rlCBCi6i6AIAbtUdJxEqpoJw8EI4P4AboDEZ6o1wM02mhvriekE+lwBkA)